# Input Data into SQL Server using Visual Studio 2012 (VisualBasic)

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, vba, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a simple form for users to input data to book a course. They fill in  the textboxes and press submit, and it needs to send an email to me with the information (I have this working) and it also needs to add it to a database (this is what I am struggling with). I also really need to understand the code so I can use it again in future.

I am making a new database/form just to get this working, then I will implement it to my working form that sends email as well.

Currently I have created a database with one table, containing: ID, Name, Course Name and Address

I have created a form with 3 text boxes (txtName, txtCourseName and txtAddress) with a submit button, but from here I am not sure how to make it so I put values in the textboxes, click the submit button and they are added to the database. Any help would be great, thanks.

Fred

Comment: Most importantly what DBMS you wanting to use? I see SqlServer but what version. Also the simplest way is to create a SQLHelper class that has your function for updating and getting of your data.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, I think its 2012 (or whatever the most recent one is, I downloaded it a few days ago) - will look into a SQLHelper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create 3 textboxes and 1 button on the form copy all this code, dont forget to name the textboxes accordingly

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim Con As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim conString As String = "This part you have to do it your self you can go to this link to check whick string works for u   http://www.connectionstrings.com/"

    Public Sub CourseSave()

        Try

            Dim con As New OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = conString
            con.Open()

            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into tablename(Name, [Course Name], Address) values('" & Me.txtName.Text & "', '" & Me.txtCourseName.Text & "', '" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "')"


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            con.Close()
            MsgBox("New Course Saved")

            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CourseSave()
    End Sub
End Class
```

if you still get errors post me the error I might be able to help you.

Comment: looks like the thing I want, though i got a few errors.

1 'cmd' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
3 'cmd' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
2 Error 2 'commandtext' is not a member of 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'.

Also, do I need any imports at the top? A lot of things I found said I would.
Finally, how do I define the connection string? Is that just the server name, or do I need a username and password and other things? I didn't put in a password when I installed SQL Server, it uses windows authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear Fred Brown, I just want to make my self clear do you need a complete code on how to connect and also to insert into the database not to forget the connectionstring. If you want that I can edit the answer and give you complete code. Just wanted to ask if that what you need. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with adding a dataset to your project,

**(Right Click Project > Add > New Item > Data > Dataset)**

Add a Table Adapter and build a SQL Select statement similar to the one below using Query Builder (which will also create your **INSERT** statement)

`Select txtName, txtCourseName , txtAddress From MyTable`

You can then call the Insert statement from your button code, along the lines of...

`Dim sta As New YourDataTableAdapter.TableAdapter

sta.Insert(txtName, txtCourseName , txtAddress)

sta.Dispose()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sb6kb28.aspx